# Decrement many values simultaneously and positionally in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection representing robots holding an inventory of products in positional slots, which will be incremented and decremented.

```
{
  _id: "someid",
  name: "",
  inventory: [{
    productId: "productId1",
    count: 30
  }, {
    productId: "productId2",
    count: 56
  }, {
    // ... up to 55 slots.
  }]
}
```

I then have an API that will interact with this document on a `PUT` request. The request data will contain the index of the `inventory` to update and the number to decrement it by, eg:

```
[
  { "inventory": 3, "inc": -10 },  // remove 10 from robot.inventory[3]
  { "inventory": 54, "inc": -2 },  // remove 2 from robot.inventory[10]
]
```

I have the following code.

```
// robots submit to this api to keep their products up to date
MachineApiV1.addRoute('/products', {
  authRequired: true,
  roleRequired: 'machine'
}, {
  put: function () {
    // omit process to get data from above
    var user = Users.findOne(this.request.headers['x-user-id']);
    Robots.update(user.profiles.robot, {
      $inc: { } // this is where I am lost.
    });
  }
});
```

I can't quite think of a way to do it in a single update. How can I increment multiple arbitrary indexes in a mongo document?

Comment: Alas, I am not using mongoose (using meteor)

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB makes it really simple - just specify the position in the array of sub-documents you want to update:

```
Robots.update(user.profiles.robot, {
  $inc: {
    'inventory.3.count': -10,
    'inventory.54.count': -2
  }
});
```